# Can't mount my Ubuntu partition from Live USB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mount

I was trying to recover grub after Windows 10 installation.
I tried BootRepair from Ubuntu Live USB, but nothing happened.
So I went to the manual way, but when I tried to mount my Ubuntu partition  with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

I got the following error

```
mount: /dev/sda4 is not a valid block device
```

What happened?
Windows 10 installation has corrupted my Ubuntu partition?

Thank you very much

Update1:

I run lsblk (thanks to the_Seppi) and this is the command output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 121.5G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.5G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.1G  1 loop /rofs
```

In addition, this is my fdisk -l

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 205006847 204800000  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       205006848 459859967 254853120 121.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       459864062 625141759 165277698  78.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       609142784 625141759  15998976   7.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

/dev/sda4 must be my Ubuntu partition, because I can exclude each other.
But that 1k size in lsblk output seems that something went really really wrong!

Comment: Is sda4 a block device? Please verify with `lsblk`

Comment: Are you sure your partition is sda4? Remember: you're running Ubuntu from USB, the device names may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There is no Ubuntu installed on your computer or the partition table is incomplete or broken.

---

In your partition list, sda4 is listed as an extended partition. This means that it doesn't actually work as a "real" partition, but as a container for subpartitions. This is done because MBR disks can only have 4 primary partitions. By doing so, one can create more than 4 partitions by creating subpartitions inside the extended partition.

Also, your partition list, you can see where your partitions start and end. Your extended partition starts at sector 459864062 and ends at sector 625141759.

As you can see, there is only one partition with its boundaries between those two values: The Swap partition, which is 7.6GiB in size and is located at the very end of the extended partition. All other partitions are outside this range.

So you have 3 primary NTFS partitions and one extended partition, which only contains a Swap partition. There is no partition which can hold a Linux installation; you don't have Ubuntu installed on your computer.

Or you do and the Windows installer erased the partition form the partition table; in this case you should be able to recover the partition entry, e.g. with the instructions given [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved with TestDisk - http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk .
It detected my Linux partition (there was, damn you Windows!) and setting it as Primary and bootable recovered both my Ubuntu installation and Grub boot selection.

Thank you very much!